# Is superuser the proper channel to ask AutoCAD-related questions?

Tags: discussion, questions, allowed-topics

After checking out all the other StackExchange sites, CAD questions do not seem to fit into any category except maybe superuser. In the FAQ, superuser is described as encompassing general software or hardware troubleshooting, which is the closest fit to an application such as AutoCAD.

Mainly I'm asking this question because I searched for "autocad" and "cad" tags, of which there are very few, and neither have a tag wiki.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can ask for questions on CAD provided it's not about recommended configurations/digitizers et al - although the response may *not* be like the others due to the niche category that CAD software belongs to